# Out labels looks strange after turning on magnification

Tags: front-end

As *everything* in Mathematica looks too small to me, so I turned on magnification when I am working.

It looks good on windows:

[image]

However, the `Out` tag is dislocated on OS X using 200% (and look at the `O` in the `Out` tag, the top is cut off):

[image]

And it became more weird with 300%:

OS X:

[image]

Windows is having problems in this case too:

[image]

Can this be reproduced? (OS X 10.10.3 Mathematica 10.1)
How can it be fixed?

Comment: What magnification setting was the above screen shot made at?

Comment: @m_goldberg updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried using different magnifications in a notebook I created in *Mathematica* V10.1.0 running on OS X 10.10.2. I only got the kind out tag displacement you show with magnification 200. All the other values I tried look OK.

Magnification 150

[image: Mag150]

Magnification 200

[image: Mag200]

It seems to me this is a bug confined to magnification 200 only. Try using magnification 150; I have poor vision and I find it big enough.